# How much do starting-blocks affect the 60m sprint?

Tags: running, track-and-field

My previous PB in the 60m was 7.21, with blocks. That was about 18 months ago, the other day I ran 60m in 7.47. I've read the blocks can effect the 100m anywhere from .2 - .4, how much will my time change with blocks to you think?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I know/assume the gain depends on how strong your quads are. The stronger the quads, the faster start and more benefit from blocks or if you start from a lower position with a more flexed knee, without blocks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).